# LOG function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am trying to convert a function from Microsoft Excel to Google Sheets.  In Microsoft Excel, it is written as `=-cellA*LOGZ(cellA;2)`. The [Microsoft help](https://support.microsoft.com/cs-cz/office/funkce-logz-4e82f196-1ca9-4747-8fb0-6c4a3abb3280) page points out that the syntax for *LOGZ* is `LOGZ(číslo, [základ])`, so I hypothesize that Excel in English will have *LOGB*, where B would stay for *base*, so `LOGB(number, [base])`. If I look on [Google Sheets help](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273#query=log), it shows the following notation: `LOG(value, base)`. So, I have constructed the following formula in Sheets: `=-D34*LOG(D34, 2)`. It ends with an error that doesn't recognize *LOG* as a function. Note that D34 is also a formula. So I wonder, where is the problem? If I place a comma in the brackets, D34 becomes black, which looks like the Google parser doesn't recognize it anymore as a variable. If I exclude coma in the brackets, it recognizes both values but still ends with an error function not recognized. And this is just one of the tests I performed. E.g. I have replaced D34 with a value or placed more brackets into my formula. It kind of looks like my use of the log function is not correct, but what is the correct function then?

Comment: I have provided [an answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/169587/) that may help you to narrow it down.  If not, I suggest sharing a demo with a minimally reproducible example using the  ["Blank Sheet Maker"](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) to protect your privacy.   More info here on Stack Exchange: [How to share a Google Sheets demo spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/)

Comment: @BlindSpots, well. I think I can [share it](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FoG8zw4psd_6zAQyKyAYA9i45mlEyvO8QIAQLZxoLXY/edit?usp=sharing), nothing to hide at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is the case that there are some locale-based differences between how logarithmic functions are named in Excel, a review of your Google sheet exposed the problem unrelated to the function names but still tied to your locale of Czechia.

##### EU vs. Non-EU Separators

This applies to *most* EU/Non-EU locales

| Locale | Decimal Separator | Formula Arguments | { Horizontal } Array Separator | { Vertical } Array Separator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Non-EU** | **<kbd>.</kbd>** period | **<kbd>,</kbd>** comma | **<kbd>,</kbd>** comma | **<kbd>;</kbd>** semi-colon |
| **EU** | **<kbd>,</kbd>** comma | **<kbd>;</kbd>** semi-colon | **<kbd>\</kbd>** back-slash | **<kbd>;</kbd>** semi-colon |

In my examples below, you need to replace the comma **<kbd>,</kbd>** which is the formula argument separator for most non-EU regions with a semi-colon **<kbd>;</kbd>** which is the correct one for your region.

```
# NON-EU
=D34*LOG(D34, 2)

# EU
=D34*LOG(D34; 2)
```

<sup><sub>**Sample Sheets Formula (Similar to Your Example)**</sub></sup>
[image]
<sup><sub>**Referenced Cell `D34` Contains a Formula (Similar to Your Example)**</sub></sup>
[image]

---

## Function Names: Czech vs. English

### 1.   Microsoft Excel

The syntax for logarithmic functions differs in Excel between Czech and English

**Excel LOGZ (Czech)**
Czech Syntax:     `LOGZ(number,[base])`
English Syntax:   `LOG(number, [base])`

**Excel LOG (Czech)**
Czech Syntax:     `LOG(number)`  
English Syntax:   `LOG10(number)`

### 2.   Google Sheets

Google Sheets uses the English versions `LOG`***** and `LOG10`
for both English and Czech.

***** <sub>Regardless of the locale/language settings, Sheets will allow `LOGZ` to be entered in place of `LOG` and will immediately replace it with `LOG` when committing/saving the formula.</sub>

### Resources

**Jak na Excel** (How to Excel)
   -   [LOGZ (LOG) - logaritmus - Excel](https://office.lasakovi.com/excel/funkce-matematicke/LOGZ-LOG-logaritmus-Excel/)
   -   [LOG (LOG10) - dekadický logaritmus - Excel](https://office.lasakovi.com/excel/funkce-matematicke/LOG-LOG10-dekadicky-logaritmus-Excel/)

**Microsoft Office Support**
  -    [Funkce LOGZ (CZ)](https://support.microsoft.com/cs-cz/office/funkce-logz-4e82f196-1ca9-4747-8fb0-6c4a3abb3280)    |     [LOG function (EN)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/log-function-4e82f196-1ca9-4747-8fb0-6c4a3abb3280)
  -    [Funkce LOG (CZ)](https://support.microsoft.com/cs-cz/office/log-funkce-c75b881b-49dd-44fb-b6f4-37e3486a0211)      |      [LOG10 function (EN)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/log10-function-c75b881b-49dd-44fb-b6f4-37e3486a0211)

**Google Sheets Support**
  -    [LOG Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093495)
  -    [LOG10 Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093423)

Comment: And from your example, it looks like it doesn't matter whether there is a space or not behind the comma/semicolon. Right?

Comment: Correct.  Spaces are often included to make code more legible.  It is a stylistic choice, except when it matters, which isn't in a list or arguments.